# How can I pass a parameter to a subsequent function call?

Tags: javascript

I've a question about subsequent function calls or somehow. I've this code here:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("localhost:8181");

socket.subscribe("abc").bind("test", function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});

subscribe(channel) {
    //Here I do some things
    return this;
}

bind(eventName, callback) {
    //Here I need the "abc" value
}
```

Currently I'm calling a second function after another to first subscribe something and then bind it. The problem is that I need the value passed to the subscribe function in the following bind function.

Currently I'm returning this because otherwise `.bind()` would be undefined because of the scope bla bla so because of this I can't just return the channel. Does someone has an idea how I can get this done without changing the function call structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `this` and also pass a variable. I think your best bet may be wrap your subscribe call in a closure so that you can keep local state.

```
function createAndSubscribe(abc) {
    // You can create other local variables here
    let otherLocal = 'foo';

    let socket = new WebSocket("localhost:8181");

    socket.subscribe(abc).bind("test", function (response) {
        // Use abc or foo here
    });

}
createAndSubscribe('abc');
```

Every time you call the function `createAndSubscribe`, it creates a unique closure that holds the value of `abc` and any other variables that you create.

Comment: As written in the title: I want to pass a parameter to a subsequent function call. In my case from subscribe() back to .bind(). I can't define it globally because when I have a lot of calls, the value would be not correct.

Comment: So as you can see, I'm first calling subscribe with a variable. When subscribe is done, I'm calling bind. I want to pass now the attribute from function a -> subscribe to function b -> bind as a return value somehow without loosing the reference.

Comment: Updated, instead of just creating a variable, you can wrap your function in a closure so that subsequent calls can't modify its state.